# Удаление содержимого флешки в Perl

Tags: perl

Написал программу, которая читает содержимое флешки и полностью удаляет его. Затем генерирует текстовый файл размером 1 Мбайт и начинает его копировать на флешку до тех пор, пока она полностью не заполнится. После этого повторно удаляет все скопированные фалы. То есть по задумке, все это сделано для безвозвратного удаления информации. До этого писал программу, которая создает один текстовый файл, но генерация хотя бы 4 Гиг текста занимает порядка 6-8 часов. Решил ускорить процесс. В итоге почему-то на флешке создается 255 файлов, а потом вылетает ошибка отсутствия файла или директории. Что посоветуете? Текст программы:

```
#!Perl/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Copy;
my ($adres, $papka, @katalog, $pozitsiya, $disk, 
    @wremya, $szen, @file, @elements);
print "Программа для очистки ветки каталога.
Введите букву диска для удаления: ";
chomp ($disk = <STDIN>);
$adres = "$disk:";                                      
OUTHER: {opendir (LISTING1, "$adres") || warn $!;
    @katalog = readdir (LISTING1);
    closedir (LISTING1);
    if (@katalog == 0) {                            #Проверяем диск на наличие файлов и каталогов
        &ZAPIS; 
        print "Диск очищен\n";
        exit};
    foreach $papka (@katalog) {                     #Если диск полон - читаем его
        next if $papka =~ /^\.\.?$/;
        $adres = "$adres"."/$papka";
        if (unlink $adres) {                        #Удаляем файлы
            $pozitsiya = rindex ($adres, "/");
            $adres = substr ($adres, 0, $pozitsiya); next}   #Возвращаемся на 1ветку вверх
        elsif (!rmdir $adres) {                     #Пробуем удалить папку
            redo OUTHER};                           #Если не получается - повторяем процедуру
        $pozitsiya = rindex ($adres, "/");
        $adres = substr ($adres, 0, $pozitsiya)};   
    $pozitsiya = rindex ($adres, "/");
    $adres = substr ($adres, 0, $pozitsiya);
    if ("$adres" eq "$disk") {$adres = "$disk:"; redo OUTHER}; 
    redo OUTHER};                                   #Таким образом проходим всё содержимое диска

sub ZAPIS {
my (@zapis, $flag, @file, $q, $w, $e, @elements, $flag2, $razmer, $file2, $flag3);  
$flag = 0; $flag2 = 1;
open (QW, ">>$disk:/Doks.txt") || die $!;           #Открываем диск для записи
while (1) {
    @zapis=chr(int (rand(127)));
    print QW @zapis;
    if ($flag%150==0) {print QW "\n"};              #Определяем длинну текстовой строки
    $flag++;
    $razmer = (stat QW)[7]; 
    if ($razmer <= 1048576) {                       #Определяем размер файла
        if ($flag%150==0) {print QW "\n"};
        $flag++; next} else {print "Размер: $razmer","\n";
        last}};
close (QW);
$q = "Doks";
while (1) {
    $w = $flag2++;
    $e = $q.$w;                                         #Создаем произвольное количество файлов
    open (QQQ, ">>$disk:/$e.txt")|| die $!;
    copy ("$disk:/Doks.txt", "$disk:/$e.txt") || die $!;    #Копируем их все на диск        
    close (QQQ)}};  
print "Диск заполнен\n";
opendir (LISTING1, "$adres") || warn $!;                #Снова читаем диск
    @katalog = readdir (LISTING1);
    closedir (LISTING1);
foreach (@katalog) {
    unlink "$disk:/$_"};                                #Удаляем все файлы
print "Ок!";
```

Comment: По Perl не подскажу, но обрати внимание - стандарт (пусть и старый) США-Пентагон - 32 перезаписи носителя информации для полного удаления инфы.

Comment: Сейчас гляну, что там за стандарт такой. Спасибо

Comment: Уважаемый Вячеслав! А ссылочка у Вас там нигде не завалялась на этот стандарт. Что то я в Яндексе туфту толбко вижу, ничего толкового....

Comment: Я читал про данный стандарт в журнале Chip (у нас в Украине есть такой компьютерный журнал). Принцип работы следующий: все форматируем, потом пишем всякую "гадость", потом снова форматируем, потом пишем... И так 32 раза (можно и 100). После этого "мусора" востановить ничего невозможно (но только не для спецслужб :)).

Comment: Не, форматировать не интерсно. Да и к тому же если запускать format из командной строки виндовс, то потом придется подтверждать нажатием enter-а. Мне так не интересно, хочу чтоб все автоматом проходило. А 32 раза, так это и тут можно сделать, что будет все удалять и по новой переписывать. И я не из хакерских побуждений а из энтузиазма....))

Comment: Оказалось что все дело В файловой системе флешки. В FAT нельзя зараз перенести больше 255 файлов вроде как. Переформатировал в FAT32 и не много изменил программу и все пошло как надо. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Н-да...

Флешка у вас судя по всему в FAT, причем похоже даже не FAT32))
Там было ограничение на количество файлов в корне, так как для их списка выделялось отдельное место, причем фиксированное.
Такого ограничения нет для директорий (папок), которые с точки зрения FAT есть файл с меткой "папка")

Во-вторых, технология чтения-записи жестких дисков и флешек достаточно сильно отличается.
В принципе для флешки достаточно одной перезаписи, чтоб затереть имеющиеся данные (32 раза нужно для магнитных дисков, для гарантированного удаления остаточной намагниченности на краях ленда (ячейки куда пишется бит)). 
Во флешках этого еффекта нет, поэтому как так кто будет пытаться востанавливать данные - очень спорный вопрос.